# JButton scale all the screen

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, java-8, jbutton

I have the following code

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Organizer");
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 700, 700);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    JButton testbutton = new JButton("testbutton");
    testbutton.setBounds(0, 0, 55, 55);

    JButton testbutton2 = new JButton("tdestbutton2");
    testbutton2.setBounds(55, 0, 44, 44);

    frame.add(testbutton2);
    frame.add(testbutton);
```

and the result sometimes is correct and sometimes is this
[image]

what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

- Don't use `setBounds()`; do use a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).
- Invoke `setVisible()` *after* adding components to the enclosing container.
- Construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

The example below adds a panel having an empty border and a `GridLayout` that is padded to match. For such an application, also consider [`JToolBar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) for the buttons and [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for the working screens.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37366846/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private static final int PAD = 50;

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, PAD, PAD));
        p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(PAD, PAD, PAD, PAD));
        p.add(new JButton("Test Button 1"));
        p.add(new JButton("Test Button 2"));
        f.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Test()::display);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which UI library you think is better?

Comment: @dios231: Out of context, it's hard to say; I almost always prefer an available Java flavor (2D, AWT, SWT, Swing, FX) for cross-platform convenience.

Answer (score 3):

```
testbutton.setBounds(0, 0, 55, 55);
testbutton.setLocation(50, 50);

testbutton2.setBounds(55, 0, 44, 44);
testbutton2.setLocation(50, 100);
```

Get rid of those statement because then do nothing.

They do nothing because the default layout manager for the content pane of a JFrame is a `BorderLayout`. The `BorderLayout` will reset the size/location of each component.

The `BorderLayout` expects you to provide a "constraint", when you add the component to the frame. If you don't provide the constraint, then the "CENTER" is used. Only a single component can be added to the "CENTER" so only the last button added is displayed.

A simple solution to understand the basic concept of using a `BorderLayout` is to use:

```
//frame.add(testbutton2);
//frame.add(testbutton);
frame.add(testbutton2, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
frame.add(testbutton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

This will display the button on two rows.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples. Download the demo code and modify that code will follow Swing conventions.

For example, you need to add components to the frame BEFORE you make the frame visible. So the order of the code should be:

```
frame.add(...);
frame.add(...);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```